# Checking for errors across all Build Configurations in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

Is there any way to have VS 2010 compile all build configurations and check for errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, go to menu Build > Batch Build and check every project/configuration you want built and click Build.

You can assign a shortcut to command Build.BatchBuild (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>), and use two key combination to make it flash fast: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.